# Android FragmentTransaction: How to generate an overlay slide in and move existing Fragement to left

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fragments

I'm trying to do the following. Create a new Fragement B (Menu), slide it in from the right, and i want to move (no hide or replace!) the already shown Fragment A to the left. 
[image]

I got the Transaction from Fragment B right, but Fragment A doesn't change his position at all. Seems like, my `FragmentManager` doesn't know that Fragment A exists (Fragment A is not added dynamically, it's defined in XML).

- main_screen_layout-xml

  ```
  <RelativeLayout //...
      android:id="@+id/main_screen"
      tools:context=".MainActivity" 

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map_screen"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
    </fragment>
  ```
- FragmentTransaction

  ```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();            
  ft.add(R.id.main_screen, new MenuFragment(), MENU_FRAGMENT); //adding Fragment B
  ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left_cut);       
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
  ```

Fragment A exists in the `FragementManager` and I can hide it, but that's not my goal

```
Fragment fragmentA = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_screen);
ft.hide(fragmentA); //hide FragmentA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Some Notes:

- I'm using the Support Libaries (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager..), but testing on API 17
- As mentioned before, I didn't declare FragmentA specifically to the `FragmentManager` (tried so, but it says Fragment already exists)
- Fragment A is (as you can see in XML) a google map from class `SupportMapFragment`
- The animation XML is working, that's why I didn't post it

Comment: I'm currently trying to archive the same thing as you did but I don't fully understand your solution. My B fragment always jumps to fill the screen after the animation finished. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Create Relative Layout with overlapping fragments:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <include layout="@layout/menu_fragment" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/front_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_screen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/map_screen_bottom_bar"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
        </fragment>
```

and simply call `.translationX(-1 * mScreenWidth)`  (mScreenWidth is my ScreenWidth minus the gap you want).

```
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame)).animate()
                    .translationX(-1 * mScreenWidth);
            } else {
                TranslateAnimation slideOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, -1
                    * mScreenWidth, 0, 0);
                slideOut.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(
                    R.integer.animation_transistion_length_short));
                slideOut.setFillEnabled(true);

                slideOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}


                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}


                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        RelativeLayout mView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame);
                        int[] pos = { mView.getLeft() - mScreenWidth,
                            mView.getTop(), mView.getRight(),
                            mView.getBottom() };
                        mView.layout(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3]);
                    }
                });

                ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame))
                    .startAnimation(slideOut);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but check out this [Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library... it allows one to slide in a fragment from the left or right while shifting the center content fragment.