# CustomAnimations on FragmentTransaction not working for the old fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

My `FragmentActivity` displays one `Fragment` at the beginning and a second when I press a `Button`. Until here, it's easy. But I got one problem with the animations.
I add the second fragment with:

```
mTChild.add(R.id.container, mFragChild).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

And to make it more "alive", I declare a `CustomAnimations` before adding the `Fragment`, it looks like this:

```
mTChild.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.alpha_out, R.anim.alpha_in, R.anim.slide_out);  
mTChild.add(R.id.container, mFragChild).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I used this method `setCustomAnimations(int,int,int,int)` *(parameters: enter, exit, popBack enter, popBack exit)* as you can see on [setCustomAnimations Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Just to understand my (basic) animations xml:

1. slide_in > the new fragment slide from right to left.
2. slide_out > back stack = fragment slide from left to right.
3. alpha_out > the old fragment disappears with alpha 100 --> 0.
4. alpha_in > back stack = old fragment appears with alpha 0 --> 100.

At this step, I got what I want **a slide in/slide out from right for the new fragment which takes place above the old fragment**. But the effect for the old fragment which normally **stays behind and disappears/appears with the alpha** not happens.

What I am doing wrong? Because, the `CustomAnimations` happens but not for the old fragment (which it not removed).
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel shame, I did a stupid mistake!

### First of all:

> Obviously I can't do this like I did, because the old fragment **stays** behind. So it can't make an **out** animation.

I answered at my own question when I asked it: *"the old fragment (which it not removed)"*... my god! So instead of:

```
mTChild.add(R.id.container, mFragChild).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I should do:

```
// REPLACE (remove+add) and not ADD only !
mTChild.replace(R.id.container, mFragChild).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

If I want an **out** animation.

---

### Nice effect:

**I found an elegant way!** Indeed, the goal was to keep the first `Fragment` visible, overlapping with a new `Fragment` (a `ListView`) and  make the older less visible to 10% (for giving a shadow/under effect). I was wrong on the way to do this.

Inspired by `SlidingMenu` and this answer [Generate an overlay slide in and move existing Fragment to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082202/android-fragmenttransaction-how-to-generate-an-overlay-slide-in-and-move-existi), I created a `FrameLayout` to **add()** *(this time no doubt)* the new `Fragment` which have a `View` to the left with a gradient background to make the shadow effect.
With this:

```
mTransaction.add(R.id.container, mChildA, null).hide(mChildA)
            .add(R.id.container2, mFrag, null).commit();
```

And after, when I press my `Button`, I do as below:

```
mTChild.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, 0, 0, R.anim.slide_out);  
mTChild.show(mChildA).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

In fact, I have the slide in and the reverse effect with the `BackStack`, and I overlay my content with a shadow on the left side. The xml of my `Fragment` it's now:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/shadowLeft"
        android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_shadow_left" />

    <ListView  
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/shadowLeft" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, I make the `FrameLayout` to "host" this layout above, with a background transparent and it works perfectly.
If someone wants to edit or give a better answer, I'm always listening. Hope this will be useful for someone who searches the same effect.

Comment: perfect, you can't see exit animation if you are using transaction.add, you need to change it to transaction.replace

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the method called "replace" instead of "add" in order to change your fragments?

Comment: Yes, I saw that... I just posted my answer... my god! How can I done that? Anyway, thank you :)