# Why previous fragment does not animate when I'm using add ?

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, fragmentmanager

I don't understand why when I do this :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_from_left,R.animator.slide_in_from_right,R.animator.slide_out_to_left,R.animator.slide_out_to_right);
transaction.replace(id, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

The new Fragment come from the right and the previous one go to the left and disappear when animation is done.

But when I use add :

```
transaction.add(id, fragment);
```

The previous fragment don't animate, only the new one come with animation.
Why ? I would like to use add and have this fragment animate like he does with replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606124/customanimations-on-fragmenttransaction-not-working-for-the-old-fragment) should answer your question. 
The gist is `transaction.add` keeps the old fragment alive along with the new fragment hence the old fragment doesn't really exit.